# how to call jquery function one after other without affecting site performance

Tags: jquery

Hi Friends I have four function in jQuery. I need to call this function one after another ie 2nd function should be worked only after 1st function complete.how can i call this function without affecting the site performance.

```
$.fn.loadcombo_Name
$.fn.loadcombo_Head
$.fn.loadcombo_Bank
$.fn.loadcombo_Remarks
```

any help will be appreciated.

Function

```
 $.fn.loadcombo_Head = function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.ParishName = $('#HF').val();
    obj.qtype = "Head";
    source = {
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [
                            { name: 'HEID' },
                            { name: 'HeadName' }
                        ]
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../DataWebService.asmx/loadcombo",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            source.localdata = data.d;
            var dataAdapter_Head = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            $("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList({
                selectedIndex: 0,
                source: dataAdapter_Head,
                displayMember: "HeadName",
                valueMember: "HEID",
                width: 220,
                height: 30
            });          
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: call them one by one in sequence but make sure that none of them have ajax call

Comment: Every function have ajax call. so what should i do

Comment: show us your ajax code

Comment: please have a look at the answer provided. see api documentation for AJAX, as we are using `.done()` and `fail()` instead of `success` and `error` callback calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can call other function after completing the first function's ajax call, so call it in `.done()` call of ajax body as shown below -

```
var loadcombo_Name = function(){
$.ajax({
url: "your url",
....
     })
     .done(function( data ) {
        $.fn.loadcombo_Head // call your function
     });
}
```

**[jQuery API Information](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

**EDIT** - you can call your next function in `success` and if you want to call it whether ajax successful or not then call it in `error` also.

```
$.fn.loadcombo_Head = function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.ParishName = $('#HF').val();
    obj.qtype = "Head";
    source = {
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [
                            { name: 'HEID' },
                            { name: 'HeadName' }
                        ]
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../DataWebService.asmx/loadcombo",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            source.localdata = data.d;
            var dataAdapter_Head = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            $("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList({
                selectedIndex: 0,
                source: dataAdapter_Head,
                displayMember: "HeadName",
                valueMember: "HEID",
                width: 220,
                height: 30
            });
            //call function
            $.fn.loadcombo_Bank          
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error");
            // call function if want to call for failure case
            $.fn.loadcombo_Bank
        }
    });
}
```

But after jQuery 1.5, `success` and `error` get deprecated and we are using `.done()` and `.fail()`. See the documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return` statement before `$.ajax()` within functions

```
var n = 0
, tasks = [
  $.fn.loadcombo_Name, $.fn.loadcombo_Head
  , $.fn.loadcombo_Bank, $.fn.loadcombo_Remarks
];

 (function task(p) {
  $.when(p[n]())
  .done(function() {
    if (n < p.length -1) {
      ++n;
      task(p)
    } else {
      console.log((n + 1) + " tasks completed")
    }
  })
}(tasks));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/cpxyfhej/